# ¿Qué quiere decir «coger oficio»?

Tags: colombia

Por el contexto en que la leí pensaba que «cojan oficio» significaba «mind your own business» pero encontré un sitio que dice que quiere decir «ponerse a trabajar».

¿Qué quiere decir en realidad? ¿Solo se usa en Colombia?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tiene ambos significados, pero ambos están relacionados.

- Encontrar algo "útil" para hacer
- Dejar de molestar y ponerse a hacer algo útil.

No se si sea otra "colombianada" pero es muy común en Colombia

Oficio significa también trabajo por lo que cojer oficio es *hacer algo productivo*

Cuando alguien está perdiendo el tiempo molestándolo a uno, pues uno lo manda a "coger oficio"

Answer (score 0):

*Coger oficio* significa haga algo de utilidad, pero el contexto en que que se utiliza puede variar un poco.

*Coja oficio!* -> Quiere decir que busque algo productivo que hacer en vez de estar haciendo lo que desencadeno la expresion.

Otra variacion es *Busque oficio!*

In other words... *Find another helpful thing to do!* or *get something to do*

Comment: Buenas, Andrés, bienvenido al sitio. No parece que tu respuesta añada nada nuevo a lo que ya respondió DGaleano hace 3 años. ¿Puedes añadir algo más? Alguna fuente que sirva de ejemplo o respalde tu afirmación, si eres de un país distinto de Colombia, etc ...

Comment: @RubioRic Es lo que pasa cuando los que son nuevos no pueden hacer comentarios. Lo digo por experiencia

Comment: @tac Ya, por eso está la opción de "Esto debería ser un comentario" al sugerir el borrado de una respuesta.

Comment: @RubioRic Rara vez vi que la gente de poder, (valga la redundancia) *pudiendo* usarlo para hacer cosas buenas, muevan esta clase de respuestas a la sección de comentarios. Veremos qué sucede...

Comment: @tac los comentarios son para pedir aclaraciones o para sugerir mejoras a una publicación. No son para responder a la pregunta, y menos cuando lo que se escribe ya está en otra respuesta. La función de "convertir en comentario" la usamos solo si el contenido de la respuesta realmente pide clarificación o sugiere mejoras. Si la respuesta tiene varios párrafos, tiene aún menos sentido convertirla en comentario.